# Scheme programming I/O and remove

Tags: scheme

I am doing a scheme project and having some issues with the coding.
For my project we have to keep a class roster(implemented as a list) and be able to perform different operations. I have two questions:

1. My write roster function opens up the file name passed through but does NOT write the list to the file and Im not sure why? you can find this function in the perform task function , when n = 2.
2. And my remove function... when I go to test it, I get the error: 
   ;The procedure #[compiled-procedure 13 ("list" #x3) #x14 #x11a2714] has been called with 4 arguments; it requires exactly 2 arguments.
   My remove function is called removestu

here is my code:

```
    (define performtask
  (lambda (n roster)
  (cond ((= n 0) (begin
                   (display "\n\tResetting roster...\n\n")
                   (menu '())
                  ))
        ((= n 1) (begin
                    (display "\n\tLoad roster from file: ")
                    (read (open-input-file (read-line)))
                    (menu roster)
                   ))
        ((= n 2) (begin
                    (display "\n\tStore roster to file: ")
                    (write roster (open-output-file (read-line)))
                    (menu roster)
                   ))
        ((= n 3) (begin
                    (display "\n\tDisplaying roster, sorted by ID:\n")
                    (printroster (select-sort roster))
                    (menu roster)
                 ))
        ((= n 4) (begin
                    (display "\n\tDisplaying roster, sorted by ID:\n")
                    (printroster (select-sort-name roster))
                    (menu roster)
                 ))
        ((= n 5) (begin
                    (display "\n\tDisplaying roster, sorted by ID:\n")
                    (printroster (select-sort-grade roster))
                    (menu roster)
                 ))
        ((= n 6) (begin
                    (display "\n\tEnter student name or ID: ")
                    (studentinfo roster (read-line))
                    (menu roster)
                 ))
        ((= n 7) (begin
                    (display "\n\tAdd a student to the class roster:\n\n")
                    (cond ((null? roster) (menu (read-3-items 0 '())))
                    (else (menu (list (read-3-items 0 '()) roster))))
                 ))
        ((= n 8) (begin
                    (display "\n\tEnter student name or ID: ")
                    (removestu roster (read-line))
                    (menu roster)
                 ))


        ((= n 9) (begin
                    (display "\n\tExiting program...\n\n")
                      #t
                 ))
        (else (begin
                    (display "\n\tTask no. ")
                    (display n)
                    (display " does not exist.\n\n")
                    (menu roster)
                 )
            )
      )
   )
)

(define studentinfo
   (lambda (lst value)
      (cond ((null? lst) (display "\n\tStudent is not found in roster.\n"))
                ((equal? (car (car lst)) value) (printrecord (car lst)))
                    ((equal? (car (cdr (car lst))) value) (printrecord (car lst)))
                         (else (studentinfo (cdr lst) value))
      )
   )
)


(define printroster
   (lambda (billy)
      (cond ((null? billy) (newline))
                (else (begin
                             (printrecord (car billy))
                                  (printroster (cdr billy))
                                    )
                          )
      )
   )
)

(define printrecord
   (lambda (lst)
      (begin
         (display "\tID=")
         (display (car lst))
         (display ", Name=")
         (display (car (cdr lst)))
         (display ", Grade=")
         (display (car (cdr (cdr lst))))
         (newline)
      )
   )
)

(define select-sort
   (lambda (roster)
      (cond ((null? roster) '())
            (else (cons (smallest roster (car roster)) (select-sort (remove roster (smallest roster (car roster))))))
      )
   )
)

(define select-sort-name
   (lambda (roster)
      (cond ((null? roster) '())
            (else (cons (smallest-name roster (car roster)) (select-sort (remove roster (smallest-name roster (car ro\
ster))))))
      )
   )
)

(define select-sort-grade
   (lambda (roster)
      (cond ((null? roster) '())
                (else (cons (smallest-grade roster (car roster)) (select-sort (remove roster (smallest-grade roster (\
car roster))))))
      )
   )
)

(define smallest
   (lambda (roster record)
      (cond ((null? roster) record)
                ((< (car (car roster)) (car record)) (smallest (cdr roster) (car roster)))
                    (else (smallest (cdr roster) record))
      )
   )
)

(define smallest-name
   (lambda (roster record)
      (cond ((null? roster) record)
            ((< (car (cdr (car roster))) (car (cdr record))) (smallest-name (cdr roster) (car roster)))
            (else (smallest-name (cdr roster) record))
      )
   )
)

(define smallest-grade
   (lambda (roster record)
      (cond ((null? roster) record)
            ((< (cdr (cdr (car roster))) (cdr (cdr record))) (smallest-grade (cdr roster) (car roster)))
            (else (smallest-grade (cdr roster) record))
      )
   )
)

(define removestu
  (lambda (roster item)
      (cond ((null? roster) '())
            ((equal? item (car roster)) (cdr roster))
            (else (cons (car roster) removestu (cdr roster) item))
      )
   )
)

(define read-3-items
   (lambda (n l)
      (cond ((= n 0) (begin
                       (display "\tStudent ID: ")
                       (read-3-items 1 (list (read)))
                            ))
                ((= n 1) (begin
                           (display "\n\tStudent name: ")
                           (read-3-items 2 (list (car l) (read-line)))
                                        ))
 ((= n 2) (begin
                               (display "\n\tGrade: ")
                               (list (car l) (car (cdr l)) (read))
                                    ))
      )
   )
)


(define menu
   (lambda (roster)
      (begin
         (display "\n\tClass roster management system\n")
          (display "\t============================\n")
           (display "\t   MENU\n")
            (display "\t============================\n")
             (display "\t0. Reset roster\n")
              (display "\t1. Load roster from file\n")
               (display "\t2. Store roster to file\n")
                (display "\t3. Display roster sorted by ID\n")
                 (display "\t4. Display roster sorted by name\n")
                  (display "\t5. Display roster sorted by grade\n")
                   (display "\t6. Display student info\n")
                    (display "\t7. Add a student to roster\n")
(display "\t8. Remove a student from roster\n")
                      (display "\t9. Exit\n\n")
                       (display "\tEnter your choice: ")
                        (performtask (read) roster)
      )
   )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `(write roster (open-output-file (read-line)))` seems ok. but you don't close the port you get from `open-output-file`. Perhaps you should use [`with-output-to-file`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_798) instead.
2. `cons` is called with 4 arguments `(cons (car roster) removestu (cdr roster) item)`. It takes only two to make a pair!

I noticed that when reading a file you don't use it. The tail call is `(menu roster)` and the result from `(read (open-input-file (read-line)))` is read and returned and, since it's not used, deleted.